# Does SQL subquery run only once for the whole SQL statement, or once for each row?

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I am not sure about SQL subqueries. If I have a sub select in select command how it is evaluated in the whole context? Does it run only once or once for each item? Is it better to use join instead?

For example

```
c.*, co.name as client_name, co.friendly_name, campaign_data, discount_sales_percent,
      u.id as user_id, u.name as user_name, u.surname as user_surname,
      (SELECT sum(cr.impressions_run) FROM campaigns_report cdmr WHERE c.id=cr.global_campaign_id) as impressions_run_total
```

Is it ok or should I use join with group by instead?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products execute things in different ways.)

Comment: You have a *correlated* subquery, it forms part of the evaluated *set* and the optimiser will almost certainly incorporate it as a join; you would validate this by reviewing the execution/explain plan.

Comment: Remember - in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. If you have two queries which are *logically equivalent*, where one uses a subquery and the other uses a join, the optimizer *should* be producing the same plan for both.

Comment: @Stu How can I review the plan?

Comment: @Čamo well that would depend on your specific RDBMS which you have chosen to keep a secret.

Comment: Its Mysql. I am sorry.